# UITextChecker in swift programming customKeyboard for iOS 8 make my keyboard crash

Tags: swift, ios8, custom-keyboard

This is my code.. I don't know where I'm going bad... 
I'm coding this in Swift Language and I want to implement auto-correction and I'm using UITextChecker, but when I press the space button the keyboard crashes... 
HELP ME!! :'(

```
@IBAction func spacePressed(button: UIButton) {
    (textDocumentProxy as UIKeyInput).insertText(" ")

    let myString = (self.textDocumentProxy as? UITextDocumentProxy)?.documentContextBeforeInput
    let textAsNSString = myString! as NSString

    var checker:UITextChecker = UITextChecker()
    var textLength = countElements(myString!)
    var checkRange:NSRange = NSMakeRange(0, textLength)

    var misspelledRange:NSRange = checker.rangeOfMisspelledWordInString(myString!, range: checkRange, startingAt: checkRange.location, wrap: false, language: "it_IT")

    var arrGuessed:NSArray = checker.guessesForWordRange(misspelledRange, inString: textAsNSString, language: "it_IT")!

    var correctedStr = textAsNSString.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(misspelledRange, withString: arrGuessed.objectAtIndex(0) as String)



}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am also experiencing it.